# How Would I Go About Creating This Doubly Linked List?

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I'm currently learning about data structures and linked lists. I'm trying to create a doubly linked list, and I'm not sure how to go about doing it. The data of the 'Node' I would like to be a class I have already created. All I can find online about linked lists, they just use integer values, and I'm not sure how best to incorporate other classes.

What I think I would to do is....

I have an abstract class 'Account'. Then classes 'Savings' and 'Checking' are derived from Account. I would Like to have the data of the 'Node' to be an account type, possibly a base class pointer so both 'Savings' and 'Checking' could be used.

What i'm not sure about is, let's say in my 'Node' class, my private data members are a base class 'Account' pointer to the account itself, a nextPointer, and a previousPointer. The class 'List' would manage the linked list, and create the new nodes. But how then would I access the member functions of the account?

I was wondering what the best way to approach this is? Should i add getters to class 'Node' which call Accounts getter functions to retrieve data about the account? Or would it be better to just make 'Savings' and 'Checking' the nodes themselves, and add a next pointer and previous pointer to the private data members?

Comment: Sticking to the OOP concepts, a List should return a list object and perform operations on the list, irrespective of what type of data could it actually refer to. Ideally to access Account, you should use an account object and call its public functions, rather than thinking of accessing those from the list or vice versa. In some exceptional cases, you can things like Friend class / functions, which are better than adding public setters

Comment: Can you just use `std::list`?

Comment: So in the Account class, should i add a next and previous pointer, and then the 'List' class manages the list of accounts?

Comment: This is just for practice. I just want to know how to create my own linked lists and manage them.

Comment: I think i see what your saying. How do you then access those objects from the list then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a generic doubly list

```
template <class T> class List{
    T value;
    Node& next; //Or Node* whatever you choose
    Node& prev;
    public:
     ...
 };
```

This way your list would serve as it should - as a list.
Now, if you need a list of accounts just declare one

```
List<Account> allAccounts = new List<Account>(); //assuming there's a default c'tor
```

And if you need to have some relations between Account and the rest you may use inheritance.

The fact that you make your list generic and not constrained to any type would make your code look more elegant, clean, and make sense.